# Jquery stream listener

Tags: jquery

I have this code part, that works so far:

```
   source = new EventSource('/formular')
   source.addEventListener 'gaga', (e) ->
   alert e
```

I tried to rewrite it with jquery but after several fails! I ask you for help!Thanks

Comment: Why would you need to rewrite three lines of something that looks like cofeescript to jQuery ?

Comment: `$(source).on('gaga', function(e) { alert(e); });` <- depending on what the class does ?

Comment: What do you mean with depending on what the class does?

Comment: The thing is with this code i handle a stream that comes from `localhost:3000/formular`